# how to pipe format-list to select string

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to use get-acl to format-list to select string.  e.g.

```
get-acl c: |Format-List
```

yields:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\geral
Owner  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Group  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         DESKTOP-RKBTEIP\geral Allow  FullControl
         S-1-15-3-65536-3852923496-3228631905-2361761901-1328441031-2492177081-392074989-583479735-4232454157 Allow
         ExecuteFile, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:SYG:SYD:P(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-21-921065058-3622932379-1743062736-1001)(A;;0x10
         0020;;;S-1-15-3-65536-3852923496-3228631905-2361761901-1328441031-2492177081-392074989-583479735-4232454157)
```

I want to select just the line with BUILTIN.  I tried

```
get-acl c: |Format-List | sls BUILTIN
```

but got no results, even though I can see that line from the first call.  How can I write this so I only get the line with the BUILTIN?

Comment: You just don't do that. Use `Where-Object` to filter objects

Comment: ok so I tried ```get-acl c: |Where-Object -Property Access -Like 'BUILTIN'``` but that didn't work.  How would you write it?

Comment: You want to filter all access rules (the objects inside the `Access` property) where the identity reference starts with builtin?

Comment: yup! that's it exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-String` is specifically for strings, to filter objects, what most PowerShell cmdlets will output, you should be using `Where-Object` among others. It seems you're looking to filter all [AccessRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.accessrule?view=net-8.0) where it's [`IdentityReference` property value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.identityreference?view=net-8.0#system-security-accesscontrol-authorizationrule-identityreference) starts with `BUILTIN`. For that you can do the following:

```
(Get-Acl C:\).Access |
    Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference.Value.StartsWith('BUILTIN') }
```

Comment: ok -- so why it I pipe get-acl to format-list, i can't do a select-string on the result?  Am I spoiled by linux grep?

Comment: @user1443098 you could if what the cmdlet outputs was a string but here 99% you are dealing with objects and objects are not meant to be filtered by a cmdlet that deals with strings such as `Select-String`.

Comment: understood though frustrated! thanks for the help.  OTOH is there a way to turn the format-list output to just lines of strings?

Comment: @user1443098 You can do `| Format-List | Oss | Select-String ...` (`oss` is an alias for `Out-String -Stream`)

Comment: nice! shorter and more readable than the alternative